# Why Keras Dense layer is expanding number of tensors in each layer

Tags: neural-network, keras

I have following model:

[image: NN]

and I wonder why is the number of parameters different for e.g. `dense_2477` and `dense_2482`? Both layers have the same amount of neurons so why do they provide different parameter numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of parameters is the number of weights connecting the layer to the previous one, so for the layer $i$ it depends on the number of neurons in the layer $i$ and the previous one $i-1$.

The exact formula for a fully connected neural network is: $$n_i(n_{i-1}+1),$$ where $n_i$ is the number of neurons in the layer $i$, $n_{i+1}$ the number of neurons in the layer $i+1$, and the $+1$ term takes into account the bias.

So for `dense_2477` you indeed get $$n_{\mathrm{params}}=8(16+1) = 136,$$ and 
for `dense_2482`, $$n_{\mathrm{params}}=16*(8+1) = 144,$$ as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Dense implements the operation: `output = activation(dot(input, kernel) + bias)` where activation is the element-wise activation function passed as the activation argument, kernel is a weights matrix created by the layer, and bias is a bias vector created by the layer (only applicable if use_bias is `True`). You can avoid this happening If you set `use_bias=False`.